# How do I add an onclick event to a Vue element by ref?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cesiumjs

I'm using Vue Cesium, and having a bit of trouble getting the desired behavior from the various Vue elements I'm adding to my map. Specifically, I want to get the element's id (created programmatically with v-for) and dispatch an action with it. I can add refs to the element. Is there a way I can programmatically add an onclick action to an element by ref? If there were a more organic way that I can use the Cesium library for this, it would be even better.

Here's the relevant element:

```
div class="viewer">
            <vc-viewer :terrainExaggeration="100" @ready="ready" :camera="camera">
                <div v-if="billboards.length > 0" v-for="billboard in billboards">
                    <vc-entity :ref="billboard.id" @click="selectCommunity(billboard.id)" :position="billboard.position" :billboard="billboard" :description="billboard.description" :id="billboard.id.toString()"> </vc-entity>
                </div>
                <vc-layer-imagery :alpha="alpha" :brightness="brightness" :contrast="contrast">
                    <vc-provider-imagery-bingmaps :url="url" :bmKey="bmKey" :mapStyle="mapStyle">
                    </vc-provider-imagery-bingmaps>
                </vc-layer-imagery>
            </vc-viewer>
        </div>
```

Comment: Would you include a code snippit so we can evaluate the problem? Specifically I'm curious to see how you're creating id's; this isn't a Vue feature.

Comment: @ChrisCamaratta done. The ID comes from the community entities which are coming from my back end.

Comment: Is the problem that the `@click="selectCommunity(billboard.id)"` isn't firing? Attaching it to the wrapping `div` instead might work better.

Comment: @ChrisCamaratta no, I tried that, didn't work either.

Comment: You can't add a click handler to a custom component unless that component emits its own click events

Comment: The map and its entities are rendered onto a canvas; they won't fire dom events so adding `@click` isn't the right way to do this. The Cesium equivalent appears to be the "pick" event, which frustratingly doesn't appear to be exposed by VC's `Entity` component. It looks like you might be able to use the [`LEFT_CLICK`](https://zouyaoji.top/vue-cesium/#/en/viewer/vc-viewer) event on the viewer and use it to find the clicked entity, if any, and take it from there. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34220203/1424869) shows an example of locating entities from events on the viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, thanks to [Zouyaoji](https://github.com/zouyaoji), appears here: https://github.com/zouyaoji/vue-cesium/issues/41#issuecomment-563029965.

In short, the vc-viewer element has two events that could be used for this: LEFT_CLICK and selectedEntityChanged.

Answer (score 2):

The Cesium equivalent to `click` appears to be the "pick" event, which, frustratingly, doesn't appear to be exposed by the VC API. It looks like you might be able to use the [`LEFT_CLICK`](https://zouyaoji.top/vue-cesium/#/en/viewer/vc-viewer) event on the viewer and use it to find the clicked entity. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34220203/1424869) shows an example of locating entities from events on the viewer.

Taking a stab at a sample impl by combining the two ref's above with your sample, something like this might work:

```html
<template>
    <vc-viewer :terrainExaggeration="100"
               @ready="ready"
               :camera="camera"
               ref="viewer"
               @LEFT_CLICK="onClick"
    >
        <vc-entity v-for="billboard in billboards"
                   :ref="billboard.id"
                   :position="billboard.position"
                   :billboard="billboard"
                   :description="billboard.description"
                   :id="billboard.id.toString()"
        />
        <vc-layer-imagery :alpha="alpha" :brightness="brightness" :contrast="contrast">
            <vc-provider-imagery-bingmaps :url="url" :bmKey="bmKey" :mapStyle="mapStyle">
            </vc-provider-imagery-bingmaps>
        </vc-layer-imagery>
    </vc-viewer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // ...ext'g
  methods: {
    // ...ext'g
    onClick (click) {
      const viewer = this.$refs.viewer;
      const pickedObject = viewer.scene.pick(click.position);
      if (Cesium.defined(pickedObject)) {
        const entityId = pickedObject.id._id;
        this.selectCommunity(entityId);
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

(completely unrelated note: it's not necessary to wrap `vc-entity` in a `div` and it *might* cause unwanted side effects.)